# Catch all changes made to Work Items in TFS 2012 Event Subscriptions

Tags: c#, event-handling

What I'm after is a way to catch all changes made to certain fields in the Work Items stored on our new TFS 2012 server, so that I can do other logic (processing the updates via a Help Desk API) with the results based on what is changed by the developers.

I've been struggling for over a week now, Googling and reading reference materials, but nothing works with TFS 2012 it seems.

I've tried the setup from:

[Developing and debugging Server Side Event Handlers in TFS 2010 (GeeksWithBlogs)](http://geekswithblogs.net/jakob/archive/2010/10/27/devleoping-and-debugging-server-side-event-handlers-in-tfs-2010.aspx)

And numerous other "trusted" sources, without luck.

I'm NOT interested in general advice, but a CONCRETE solution to this problem.
It's probably more than one way to do this, but I'll settle for one that works.

I've delayed this part of the application development until near deadline, because when first reading up on it it seemed like a simple thing to do. I imagined I could just use the Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client libraries to do this work, but it turns out that there isn't a pre-defined Event to subscribe to from client code. (Or I haven't found it).
So I guess I need to create a custom Event handler and install it to the Plugins directory on TFS, like described in the above mentioned link, but when I do this I get an exception while debugging TFS and nothing happens:

```
First-chance exception at 0x000007FEFD90BCCD (KernelBase.dll) in w3wp.exe
```

So now I'm over my deadline, searching in panic for a doable solution to this, before resorting to some manual way to periodically loop through and check the WorkItems like I had to do with the tickets on the Help Desk side of the application.

If I knew more about Events and Delegates, I guess I'd be able to create a good solution to this, but I don't, and I'm in the process of learning C# right now, so...

Comment: I would try this on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: Why would this possibly be off-topic?

Comment: I've figured this one out, and I'll answer my own question soon.

Comment: The link is (effectively) broken. It redirects to *[Geekswithblogs.net, the End of an Era](http://julian.farm/geekswithblogs/?url=/mtreadwell/archive/2004/06/06/6123.aspx)*.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a TFS `ISubscriber` event handler is the most efficient way to manipulate data inside TFS. It is important that your plugin is built against the right .NET Framework version and is  either AnyCPU or x64. x86 binaries cannot be loaded in TFS 2012 (which is x64 only). Plus, in TFS 2012, these plugins should be .NET 4.0/4.5 now, and they must reference the 11.0.0.0 server bits.

Without more details of the exact exception, which might have been logged to the eventlog or which you might be able to find by attaching a debugger to your TFS web application, we cannot help you debug the problems you are experiencing with your current implementation.

As an alternative, you can use the 'old style' SOAP event handler, which is easier to work with, since it requires you to use the Client Object Model. Plus, it's much easier to debug, since it can run on your local machine without the need to install a complete TFS instance. In TFS 2012 you can configure these types of alerts from the Web Access interface by clicking on your name (upper right corner), then choosing "My Alerts".

Click the "Team alerts can be managed from the Advanced Alerts Management Page" link to configure a new event and set it's "Format" to "SOAP".  In the "Send To" you can specify the web service URL that must be invoked by TFS to process these alerts.

The simplest way to create such a service, is to create a simple .asmx web service and add one method with the following signature:

```
 [SoapDocumentMethod(Action="http://schemas.microsoft.com/TeamFoundation/2005/06/Services/Notification/03/Notify", RequestNamespace = " http://schemas.microsoft.com/TeamFoundation/2005/06/Services/Notification/03")]
 [WebMethod(MessageName=”Notify”)]
 public void Notify(string eventXml)
 {
         //Write your custom code here
         //Use eventXml to extract event related fields and their values
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Resolved it by performing the following steps
a) Reference the 11.0.0.0 version of following assembplies

```
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.dll
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.dll
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.dll
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.dll
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Server.DataAccessLayer.dll
```

b) Changed target framework to .NET Framework 4