# Achieve Change Tracking in TFS 2012

Tags: change-tracking

I have installed TFS2012 on my server, now I need to achieve change tracking.I have explained the details below.

The whole idea of change tracking is, if I change the PBI/Requirement the all linked work items/bugs/impediments status should be changed or TFS should notify me in some way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TFS will not automatically update one Work Item when a linked item changes. There is no functionality for that out-of-the-box. What you can do is [configure an alert](http://www.incyclesoftware.com/2012/08/setup-alerts-tfs-2012/).

Or you can test whether the [TFS Aggregator that exists for TSF 2010](http://tfsaggregator.codeplex.com/) (open source project) will work for 2012 (not officially supported). It can update child or parent work items when a workitem in the hierarchy changes.

---

What you want is not possible in TFS out of the box, but you can implement this with relative ease using a custom `ISubscriber` or a SOAP webservice. See [the following answer on question regarding this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14203915/736079).

Comment: I checked the link you have sent to setup alerts. But what I want is that if Parent Work Items changes I should send a notification with the list of child Work Items included in body of email. As I know ALM this is a basic feature of every ALM. It just says that if requirement changes the dependent areas in the application like testcases,code,unit tests will chnage. that is what I want to achieve.

Comment: Updated my answer with a way to do this using the TFS API. There is no way to do this out-of-the-box.